Hidden views attachment in the pages 1 and next
I've spent the whole weekend trying to work with views attachments, and the only thing I’ve managed to do is use the hook_views_pre_render to hide them.
Functionality
What I’m aiming for is that the attachment appears only on the first page, as it contains featured content, and then disappears on page 1 and beyond.
What I’ve Tried
I’ve looked into configuring this via the attachment options, but no luck. I also tried using contextual filters and an option that existed in Drupal 7 (back when using PHP in views was more common in those "wild west" days), but it seems like this option no longer exists, or at least I haven’t found it.
I also reviewed the Global NULL contextual filter in code, but I couldn’t figure out how to make a filter that returns no results. Ultimately, the options that this filter offers in the validator are either to show all results or display a message, which doesn’t solve the issue. 
Another approach I thought about was using a view block. The Condition Query module exists for this, but since the project is set up to use context, I can’t use it, as context only allows defining a single context (in my case it's the path). The only solution I see in this case would be to have two contexts: one for the featured block and another for the rest of the blocks in that path. However, I’m unsure about how good or maintainable it would be to split this functionality into multiple contexts (viewing the functionality as the URL representation).
The third option I considered was creating a custom block that would display the view block, and then in blockAccess or build, determine whether it should render or not by checking the URL's query_params.
The fourth option would be to create an access for that attachment which, instead of checking user permissions, would check the query_params.
In the end, I’m left with pre_render, but I still have this feeling that I haven’t found the "optimal" way to implement this functionality.
Is there any other way besides hook_views_pre_render to control the visibility of attachments?

I've done the inverse, only enabling an attachment for page 2 and beyond, and I believe I also used a pre_render hook, adding a CSS class, with which I hid the attachment visually on page one.

I find a partial solutions, it's not my case but for another one.
With Display Suit you can choose to have the X first elements from a view with a different view mode, and choose to make it in the first page only.
It's not my case 'cause the attachment node are set with a queue.
